# Removing Sprite From Array

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, nsmutablearray, sprite

I have a "snake game" like player and I'm running into some problems when removing the end tail piece when the body reaches a certain length. Right now I have this:

```
if (i > maxHealth) {
    id object = [tail objectAtIndex:i-maxHealth-1];
    [tail removeObject:object];//This part doesn't work, if I comment this line out it works but the object is still in the array 
    [self.tileMap removeChild:object cleanup:YES];
}
```

Where `i` is the length of the "snake" when the scene is init `i` is equal to 0 and the player moves it adds the "tail" image to the scene and to a NSMutableArray called *tail*. I get this in the debugger:

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: index 4 beyond bounds [0 .. 2]'`

Which doesn't make any sense to me because before I added the line to remove the sprite from the array and just use `object` to remove the sprite from the scene it worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should learn how to work with breakpoints to identify the right place in your code, because clearly, your problem is not the line you think it is:

> [__NSArrayM **insertObject:atIndex:**]: index 4 beyond bounds [0 .. 2]'

It basically tells you all there is to know: you are trying to insert an object at index 4 of an array that only has three indices (0,1,2).
So, your call to **removeObject** is not the reason for the exception you get, but the cause for this exception, happening later, when you try to **insert an Object**.

I guess the index is wrong, apparently, because you removed your object at index 3 or 4 in the step before but did not update the valid indices.

To fix these kinds of problems, I recommend to go to the Breakpoints Navigator in Xcode (cmd+6) and click the small bottem left "+" and "Add Exception Breakpoint" set to "all". Run your code and the debugger will pop up right where the exception happens.

Comment: When I remove an item from an array, do the items after it get shifted down? ex: array = 0,1,2 remove 0, 1 goes to 0 and 2 goes 1?

Comment: No, it does not shift. It's all in the docs: "NSMutableArray -removeObject: This method uses indexOfObject: to locate matches and then removes them by using removeObjectAtIndex:. Thus, matches are determined on the basis of an object’s response to the isEqual: message"

Comment: @stenger96 While not knowing the complete internals of the NSMutableArray you can certainly access elements from your array contiguously after removing an item from the middle of the array.  If I remove element 50 from a 100 element array I can access elements from 0 to 98 (inclusive) by index one after the other so they elements do sort of shift in the sense that you can continue to access elements sequentially in the array.  In memory I'm not sure how NSMutableArray handles that since its transparent to the developer and for most people it doesn't matter anyway.

Comment: @stenger96 auco gave you some good info.  Doesn't like the issue lies with the code sample you gave.  The error is for an insertion into the array and you are doing no insertions to any array in that code block.  If you enable the exception breakpoint it should show you the offending line of code and you can address the issue.

Comment: Ignore my last comment, I really think removing object 0 in a NSMutableArray shifts the following objects down because every time I move my player I'm adding a new object to the array, but the array never has an index past 2 (0,1,2 = 3, which is the max length of the player)

Comment: @stenger96: I think you're still laboring on the wrong side of things: your app is not crashing when you **remove** the object, but when you **add** a new one. And: as Rob already mentioned, you don't show that code to us. Maybe you should switch to NSMutableSet if the order of objects is not important and giving you trouble. Edit: or look for NSArray push:/pop: categories in the wild if you need a pushing-popping NSArray.

Comment: The app doesn't crash with the addition of `i-=1` which lowers `i` so that it's not trying to add the next tail piece at position `i` which would be out of bounds.